# Importing module for python files not working on OSX

Tags: python, pip, python-module

When trying to import selenium using pip3 on vscode, I keep producing the error,
"import selenium
ImportError: No module named selenium"

I have looked through other posts but was not able to find a solution to  my problem. However I believe I can provide some information that can help others guide me to the correct solution. I believe it may be something with the python PATH or pip3 is installing them into a directory that python is not reading

```
$ which python
usr/bin/python
```

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

```
$ pip3 show selenium
Location: /Users/*********/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 23.1.2 from /Users/*********/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```